# gradle release plugin automatic version pattern

Tags: regex, jenkins, gradle, gradle-release-plugin

I'm using [gradle-release-plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) with jenkins and I want use

```
gradle release -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true
```

to automatic increase version.

But this automatic move the ".patch" number (assume `major.minor.patch` version) and I'm trying to move the ".minor" number.

For example if release 1.3.17 then newVersion 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT

I would change this automatic replace without use the 
`release.releaseVersion` and `release.newVersion`

It could be done with the plugin configuration `versionPatterns` ?

Maybe using this pattern `/[.]*\.(\d+)\.(\d+)[.]*/` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Auto answer...

After some research and tests I could move the `minor` version number (assume `major.minor.patch` version)  with the param `release.useAutomaticVersion=true`

Just need to configure the `versionPatterns` plugin parameter with this closure:

```
versionPatterns = [
        // Increments minor number: "2.5.17-SNAPSHOT" => "2.6.0-SNAPSHOT"
        /[.]*\.(\d+)\.(\d+)[.]*/: { Matcher m, Project p -> m.replaceAll(".${(m[0][1] as int) + 1}.0") }
    ]
```

Really it isn't the only change needed in the build.gradle, this closure code depends to add this import previously:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
```